# Split each line of the file into a new file in TCL

Tags: tcl

I am trying to read each line in a file and copy that line to a new file. Then second line into the second file and so on. I am using the following code but instead of one line I get all lines in each file. Many thanks in advance

```
set fp [open "point_dip.txt" r ]
set file_data [read $fp]
set lines [split $file_data "\n"]

set ii 1

foreach line $lines {
    set filename "$ii.txt"

    set fileId [open $filename "w"]
    puts -nonewline $fileId $lines
    close $fileId

    set ii [expr $ii + 1]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a typing mistake. The following line:

```
puts -nonewline $fileId $lines
```

should be:

```
puts -nonewline $fileId $line
```

That is without `s` because with `s`, the variable `$lines` contains all the lines.

You can also use `incr ii` instead of `set ii [expr $ii + 1]` and you should indent your lines correctly, even if it doesn't matter much in Tcl. It's just to improve readability.

Comment: Might be it is also a good idea to open file $ii.txt outside foreach loop and close it after.

Comment: @RomanKaganovich Err, I don't think that'd work. You would end up with one file with all the lines in it.

Comment: Oops! Yes , I didn't notice the condition to write each line to the new file. Sorry, my mistake.